# Twilio: Outbound Call with IVR

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Excuse my ignorance, but all of the documentation on the Twilio website shows how to handle inbound IVR calls (customer calls your number). I want to do the opposite: I want to initiate an outbound call (from my application to the customer), and have the user be able to interact with an IVR I have programmed in response.

Is there anyway to do this? I have spent a few hours pouring over the Twilio documentation but it doesn't seem like an outbound call with IVR functionality is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The most direct and scalable way to implement an outbound IVR is using Twilio Studio. You will use the REST API Trigger path, as documented in the article below.

[Trigger a Twilio Studio Flow Execution via the REST API](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007778153-Trigger-a-Twilio-Studio-Flow-Execution-via-the-REST-API)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I was wondering if using Twilio Studio Flow allows for the same flexibility as the standard IVR functionality? I just want to be able to initiate an outbound call with the standard IVR features.

Comment: How to trigger a call: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls?code-sample=code-make-an-outbound-call-to-a-phone-number&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x#initiate-an-outbound-call-with-twilio and pass the url of the IVR you have programmed.

Comment: @foadster - why would you think otherwise?